# Save multiple rows with multiple arrays - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, row

I have a big problem on saving multiple rows with multiple arrays into MYSQL. For example row 1 contains "name" and "share percentage". Then they add another 2 rows which contains same attributes as mentioned. So how do I save these data into DB. Below was my unsuccessful code:

```
foreach($_POST['name_members'] as $dir){ // array 1
    $directorID = run_num('director_id','proc_director'); // generate running number for each row
    foreach($_POST['share_percentage'] as $share) { //array 2
        $insDirector = "INSERT INTO 
                            proc_director(director_id, vendor_cd, director_name, director_percentage)
                        VALUES
                            ('$directorID','$vendorID','".trim(addslashes($dir))."','$share')"; 
        $db->query($insDirector); // save the array value into DB
    }                            
}
```

I made demo interface, so that you can get the picture what I want. Here the hyperlink: http://softboxkid.com/blog/code/add_row/

Comment: what is the error you receive?

Comment: I didn't receive any error but when try to insert 2 rows they insert 9 rows

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['name_members'])` and `var_dump($_POST['share_percentage'])` please

Comment: What database library are you using? `addslashes` is not sufficient protection against SQL injection

Comment: Big problem sounds good. Post the generated Query $insDirector just before the line $db->query($insDirector);

Comment: Please edit your question, don't put the `var_dump()` in the comments. It is hard to read when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your respond. I already found the solution for my problem. Here is my code:

```
/* save partnerhip information */
                $count_director = count(array_trim($_POST['name_members']));

                for($i=0; $i<$count_director; $i++) {
                    $directorID[] = run_num('director_id','proc_director'); // generate running number for each row

                    $insDirector = "INSERT INTO proc_director(director_id, vendor_cd, director_name, director_percentage)
                                         VALUES('".$directorID[$i]."','".$vendorID."','".$_POST['name_members'][$i]."','".intval($_POST['share_percentage'][$i])."')";
                    $db->query($insDirector); // save the array value into DB
                }
```